# Receiving error when trying to use postman for API

Tags: json, api, post, http-status-code-405

I'm getting the below message when trying to post to an api

"code" : 1,
"type" : "error",
"message" : "RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header"

i am trying to hit an api to send an update. i send this as a raw json.
{
"products" : ["194839"],
"fieldName": “SHIPMENTREFERENCE”,
"fieldValue": “test”
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use a POST method but the error you sent is saying that POST is not allowed on the resources you are trying to access with your JSON.

This is a 405 HTTP status code error indicating that the POST method is not allowed.

I would suggest you double check the following:

1. If the URL is correct.
2. If the API needs authentication in the form of secret keys.
3. Check if the API documentation supports the POST method.
4. Check the format of the JSON you are trying to pass in your post method, comparing it to what is described in the API documentation.